# VTD-XML declareVariableExpr invalid char #

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

I want to declare a variable Expression with the function declareVariableExpr(..,..) but in the value of my variable I have the "#" character.
VTD returns an error for this char, saying it is an invalid char.
Anyone can help me to resolve this problem please ?

```
String idproduct=text("./product");//with an # like: myidproductvalue#245315
ap.declareVariableExpr("id",idproduct);
ap.SelectXpath("./ProductData/Data/keyId[text()='$id']/parent::node()");
if(ap.evalXpath()!=-1){
.....
}
```

It returned me , this error :

```
com.ximplemware.XPATHParseException : Invalid Char in name token: 
myidproductvalue#245315; @position16
```

Comment: Could you share some of your code?

Comment: @tannerburton hello i add it , thanks